# Make Nodejs encrypt and decrypt function up to date

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make my small function up to date, it generate 2 warnings:

(node:8944) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
(node:8944) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr:

Code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
password = 'd6F3Efeq';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}
 
function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}
```

This encrypt and decrypt wonderfully, but it generate some errors. I tried the new syntax, and I have a hard time figuring it out. If someone could provide an up to date demo, you're the best. Thank you

PS: I don't want to use createDecipherIv, I only want to use a key if this make sense

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: use `createDecipheriv`.   example here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-createdecipheriv-method/

Comment: I've class which does all dirty stuff, I hope that will give You idea. https://gist.github.com/num8er/9233f6c5397418ec428debe30da3e23f

Comment: what about this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js  it has almost same idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js):

```
npm i --save crypto-js
```

and use it:

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js'),
password = 'd6F3Efeq';

function encrypt(text){
  const result = crypto.AES.encrypt(text, password);
  return result.toString();
}
 
function decrypt(text){
  const result = crypto.AES.decrypt(text, password);
  return result.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
}
```

or You can use [cryptr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptr)